# Render Import Statement Unused

Tags: python, django-views, render

I'm trying to build my first DJango project. I'm using PyCharm for my IDE. In my view.py folder I noticed that the "from django.shortcuts import render" is grayed out and when I hover over it, it has a message that says Unused import statement "from django.shortcuts import render". Will this affect my project? Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: The message is just telling you that you imported `render` but aren't using it.  You can just delete that line.  Or write the part of your code that uses `render` and then it won't be unused any more.  Or just leave it; the "unused import statement" is a helpful hint that you can use to clean up useless code, but useless code won't break your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module but do not use it in your code, Pycharm marks it as unused. Although leaving the import statement there will not affect your project, if the module is not being used it is best to remove the import.